# How to find HTTP request details

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to redirect from `www.abc.com` to `www.xyz.com`.

When I redirectd to `www.xyz.com` at that time how I know about details of GET method of HTTP . so that I come to know this request come from `www.abc.com`.

As both application hosted on different sever. I tried HTTP Handler for `www.xyz.com`, but I am unable to get details of HTTP when request method is GET. My handler and module event unable to call at time of redirect.

Comment: If you want to follow W3C recommendations, you should set `Origin` header.

Comment: Another option is to set a query string parameter in your GET request to your target URL, like `www.xyz.com/?origin=abc.com`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass hint, for example a parameter saying returnURL=abc.com.
And in the XYZ.com, check for the URL parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you redirect the request, your header will have the [Referrer](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.36) information which can be retrievable from the target server.  For more details about *HTTP Referrer* please click [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer)